# Error using history mode Laravel with VueJS

Tags: laravel, vue.js, single-page-application

I want to make a web singlePage app made with Laravel and VueJS without the "#" that gives when I visit a page.

I'm using

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  history: false
  ...
```

and

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
   return view('welcome');
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

But everytime I make a reload in the page my assets are not rendering.
I have the next error for some js files.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: Try setting `processUrls` to false in the mix config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd check file links. In my experience, the (JavaScript) file you are linking to is returning 404 page. In other words, the browser is expecting your file (i.e. path/file.js) but it is returning HTML results (because the start tag of most html elements is `<`, i.e. `<`html>, which is not valid JS).

Check that the file(s) you're loading are accessible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes the browser was expecting path/file.js, I changed the source to /file.js and it worked!, now I have my app without the hashtag.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help! Fell victim to that myself many times, and I knew the (a possible) culprit straight away

Comment: @LuisFernandoLópezRuiz where you change the source ( in mix) ?

Comment: @MalekBenelouafi I changed the source in every place where my app was expecting an imported script, css or image. I was importing the resources with "./file.js" not "/file.js"